# Dynamic Django form not only with inputs

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I haven't used Django for long and I have a dynamic Django form:

```
   class GoodsAddPropertyForm(forms.Form):
     def __init__(self, groups_and_properties, *args, **kwargs):
      super(GoodsAddPropertyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      for group_and_properties in groups_and_properties:
       self.fields[group_and_properties.name] = CharField(label = group_and_properties)
       for property in group_and_properties.properties:
           if property.type == 'boolean':
               self.fields[property.name] = forms.BooleanField(label = property.name, required=False)
           elif property.type == 'float':
               self.fields[property.name] = forms.FloatField(label = property.name)
```

How can I make that `self.fields[group_and_properties.name]` = `CharField(label = group_and_properties)`  will be a simple HTML text without an input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom widget:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

    class HTMLWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
        def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
            output = []
            output.append('<p>Hello world: %s</p>' % value)
            return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```

The specify it as your CharField widget:

```
self.fields[group_and_properties.name] = CharField(label = group_and_properties, widget = HTMLWidget())
```

Answer (score -1):

You should look at forms.MultiValueField and forms.MultiWidget. But it doesnt fine, so you have to subclass them.